# How to set my color to action bar?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,and i'm using this code for change my action bar color:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

but i want to set my this color to my action bar:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(0x0054a6);
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Then use `cd` as parameter to `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: please post your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF0054A6));
```

Hex code starts with opacity. So add FF(fully opaque) to your color.

Comment: ok,please wait for 8 minute to accept your post.thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a good idea to keep all color values in the resources xml.

To adjust the style of your theme, you can use the `style.xml` to override the theme colors (inkl. action bar) like this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/GParmPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/GParmPrimary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/GParmAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```